# How to show/hide a view/layout on switch click in android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm creating a Setting activity whether user will be able to activate/deactivate notifications. Now I want to show/hide certain options on the click of  switch button. I'm able to hide the view but dunno how to show that again? Here I'm  pasting my switch code :

```
    notify.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(b)
            {

                notifyMail.animate()
                        .translationY(0)
                        .alpha(0.0f)
                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                notifyMail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
                notifyPhone.animate()
                        .translationY(0)
                        .alpha(0.0f)
                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                notifyPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
                notifyHitcher.animate()
                        .translationY(0)
                        .alpha(0.0f)
                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                notifyHitcher.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
                notifyDriver.animate()
                        .translationY(0)
                        .alpha(0.0f)
                        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                                notifyDriver.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });



            }
            else
            {
                notifyMail.animate().translationY(0);


            }
        }
    });
```

The rest of the part is to be done in else {}. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you hide your views twice (visibility and alpha value)!

first you have to set your view to visible:

```
notifyDriver.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

at this point the view is visible, but transparent, because the alpha value is 0.

so you have to set the alpha value back to 1 like you did it before:

```
notifyDriver.animate().alpha(1.0f);
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is set it back to visible. Like this 
  notifyDriver.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: Thanks for the response  but I tried that it make the view responsive but doesn't show anything just white space.

Answer (score 1):

Just call

```
notifyDriver.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response  but I tried that it make the view responsive but doesn't show anything just white space.

Comment: I never had a problem with this method. Can you explain `it make the view responsive` ?

Comment: ok. See i've placed a spinner inside notifyDriver/notifyHitcher , when i tap on the place of picker it work but doesn't show the control on the screen? I hope you're getting my point